# Generic `make` rule for generating object files from source files

Tags: makefile, nmake

I have all my source files in a directory called `src` and I would like all object files to be placed in a directory `obj`. It is possible to write a generic `make` rule (that preferably also works with `nmake`) that will generate the object file corresponding to the source file and place it in the correct directory?

Comment: It's trivial to do this in, for example, GNU make.  I have no idea how to do it in nmake.

Comment: @MadScientist How would I do it? I only found the `.c.o` syntax which translates C sources to object files within the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

With nmake, you can use an inference rule with paths:

```
{src\}.c{obj\}.obj:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1):

For GNU make you can use pattern rules, like so:

```
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```